# Ending sentence with a single word following ... what punctuation?

Tags: grammar, symbols

I am currently writing an essay for school and ran into a problem that neither my friends nor I could solve.

> Without any consequences for poor behavior, whether the consequences be outwardly applied like being grounded by a parent, or an emotional response like feeling ashamed for upsetting a peer, there is no development of a trait necessary in civilized humans, **empathy**.

I would like to end my sentence with a single word to emphasize what the rest of my paper will be about. I believe there is a correct form of punctuation to lead on to the summarising word, but am not sure what it is. Perhaps a hyphen?

Also I don't want to say "i.e."

Comment: It just dawned on me there was a song referencing this exact topic, "Semicolon" by The Lonely Island. It ends with someone saying "actually those are examples of colons". That considered, should the symbol considered be a colon?

Comment: Your sentence doesn't parse.

Comment: By hyphen, you actually mean dash. Hyphens are used for word-joining. Dashes are longer—like this.

Comment: What Peter Shor said. More precisely, it should be an **em**-dash; see [here](http://www.techtoolsforwriters.com/how-to-create-an-em-dash/) for how to make one. Having said that, I think a colon would work better in this case. Note that the rest of the sentence should be corrected as well, e.g. by inserting *for* before *civilized* (as Ash suggested in his answer).

Comment: What @HotLicks is referring to is that since everything before *they do not develop* is an introductory clause, when you remove all that you are left with *they do not develop a necessary trait civilized humans, empathy*; and this is not a grammatical sentence no matter how you connect *empathy*.

Comment: Note also that some like myself would see zero need for using *be* in the first clause: that is some kind of old fashioned subjunctivy word usage.

Comment: I think there are legitimate arguments for comma, colon, or dash before the final word.  Semicolon is the least desirable choice.

Comment: You can't develop empathy. You can develop compassion and sympathy, but you have to have been in a similar situation to someone to express empathy. Example: I could express sympathy towards my wife when she was in labour, but, as a man, there is no way I could express empathy. One richness of English is the variety of different words to express different meanings. One helps destroy this language if one contrives to destroy this distinction by misusing words merely because they seem trendy.

Comment: Sentences end with a full stop (period) and the one you quote, not before time. If you want to indicate that you thesis follows, a short sentence is a good way to emphasize that point. e.g. "This is what my paper is about." The pause caused by the stop helps focus the reader on the next sentence.

Comment: Here's a tip for you: use "such as" instead of like. As for empathy, one can develop it where there had been none. For example, maybe I hate my neighbor because his dog barks all the time and he makes noise all night. Then, I find out his daughter died in a  horrible accident. After that, I find that I have developed empathy for him. That does not mean I will tell him how I feel about his situation.

Comment: What does this mean?? "there is no development of a trait necessary in civilized humans"? Do you mean: humans have never developed the one  trait needed to civilize them: empathy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest

> [1] *...they do not develop a trait (that is) necessary for civilized humans: empathy.*

Note that I've rewritten the part before *empathy* slightly. What is written in the original post is not acceptable English, as others have already pointed out. A minimal change that would make it acceptable is *a necessary trait **for** civilized humans*, but I personally prefer [1].

Now about the colon: it would also be **acceptable** to use a **comma** or an **em-dash** instead of the colon. But since you are trying to emphasize *empathy* particularly strongly, I think a colon works the best.

**Discussion**

I will follow [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), pp. 1350-1362, 1741.

In [1], *empathy* functions as an **asyndetic subclausal supplement**. This needs a bit of explaining.

A **supplement** is a word or a word group that is not syntactically integrated with the rest of the sentence. Instead, it bears a purely **semantic** relation to some part (called the **anchor**) of the main sentence.

The **asyndectic** vs **syndectic** distinction has to do with with, respectively, the absence or presence of so-called **indicators**. These are phrases like *namely*, *that is*, *especially*, etc., whose function is to clarify the relation of the supplement to its anchor. Since there are no indicators in [1], the supplementation is asyndectic.

Now, asyndetic subclausal supplementation comes in two flavors, illustrated in [2]:

[2] a. *They went to Bill Clinton, **the only man who could help them**.*
      b. *They went to the only man who could help them: **Bill Clinton**.*

In both [2a] and [2b], the boldfaced words are the supplement. The difference between them is that in [2a], the supplement provides only **descriptive** information, whereas in [2b], it provides **identifying** information.

This distinction is relevant for the choice of punctuation. A comma is acceptable in both [2a] and [2b]. In contrast, a colon is acceptable only in [2b], where the supplement provides identifying information.

Your case is like [2b]. Just like in [2b], you could precede the supplement with either a comma or a colon (or even an em-dash). And, like in [2b], a colon works better that a comma (and, I think, better than an em-dash, too).

Comment: The question should be close-voted but this answer is worth keeping.